# feedback on my answer regarding set intersections.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Prove or find a counter-example to the claim that for all sets $A,B,C$ if $A\cap B = B \cap  C = A \cap C = \emptyset$,  then $A \cap B \cap C=\emptyset $.

the above statement is not true so i need a counter example but i do not know to do that.i  have tried but in the end i somehow get lost. please try give answer in simplest way possible.
Let A={1,2,3} , B={4,5,6} and C={7,8,9}. It is then clear that A∩B=B∩C=A∩C=∅ ?

Comment: is this a homework question?

Comment: yes it is a homework question

Comment: then why did you not tag it as such?

Comment: forgot about when i saw this question

Comment: Is there something missing from the title? The question seems incomplete.

Comment: also, please refrain from posting the question in the title. That is not what titles are for. Also, you need to use latex commands between dollar signs to make things readable. I edited your question a bit so you can see how it's done.

Comment: what seems to confuse you about the answer you gave? it is a correct counter example, but if it is not clear to you, and since you need to explain your answer, maybe it's a good idea that you actually post your explanation as well. That may help you clarify things and will get you better answers.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A,B,C $ be sets. If $A \cap B = \emptyset$ then $A \cap B \cap C = (A \cap B) \cap C = \emptyset \cap C = \emptyset $. Or did i miss something?